# I want to write code once and run it on multiple platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac, Android, iOS). Is there any programming language related to this?

Tags: android, linux, windows, cross-platform, code-reuse

Language must has disaply images, play videos feature. Platform wise wrapper is acceptable but no more change required to run it on any of these 5 platforms.

- Windows
- Linux
- Mac
- Android
- iOS

Answer (score 1):

Flutter is an app SDK for building high-performance, high-fidelity apps for iOS, Android, web (beta), and desktop (technical preview) from a single codebase.
And you can also React Native it is very similar to Flutter

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/),

which is an open source mobile UI toolkit for building high quality, cross-platform native and web app experiences.